# FFMPEG video Zoom to a Position X Y

Tags: ffmpeg

I want during zoom, zoom position is constantly changing as the video below

https://youtu.be/hdFlP7ir07g

This is the code I tried. 
But it does not work continuously but only works for the first 3 seconds

Thank you for taking time for me

```
 ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp4 -vf "scale=iw*4:ih*4,zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(on,125),50),zoom+0.5,zoom-0.5)':x='iw/2-iw*(1/2-88/100)*on/150-iw/zoom/3':y='ih/2-ih*(1/2-94/100)*on/150-ih/zoom/3':d=0"  -c:v libx264  -s "1280x720" out.mp4
```

Comment: Hi Pilonas! Can you please try to better specify what you want to achieve? The first sentence of your question doesn't make any sense to me. The video you linked contains many 'effect' it would be much better if you could post a short video showing only the effect you want to achieve, or at least specify a short time-frame in the referenced video. Please try to clarify your question.

Comment: Note that the `on` variable represents output frames count https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-zoompan. It is responsible for the time limitation of the effect you observe.

Comment: @Isolin 
I want when during zoom it will have zigzag effect. Can you help me, or how can the effect continue forever, not just the first time

Comment: I am sorry, but I have difficulties finding out what is a _zigzag_ effect. You mean something like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOMqG0osxWM